# Pagination shows more than set limit

Tags: php, magento, collections, pagination, magento-1.9

I am fairly new to Magento and I am having an issue with pagination on a custom collection. I have the page limit set to 5, however, all six results show (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44oWz.png)).

```php
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    //............

    $oItems = new Varien_Data_Collection();

    foreach ($collection as $col) {
        $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($col->getId());
        $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        //Mage::log(count($items));
        foreach($items as $item) {
            $varienObject = new Varien_Object();
            $varienObject->setName($item->getName());
            $varienObject->setProductId($item->getProductId());
            $varienObject->setProductOptions($item->getProductOptions());
            $oItems->addItem($varienObject);
        }
    }

    $this->setCollection($oItems);
}

protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();

    $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
    $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,25=>25,'All'=>'All'));
    $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
    $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
    $this->getCollection()->load();
    return $this;
}
```

I know I have to be close, but I am missing something obviously.